# Flutter textfieldcontroller default value not working with variable

Tags: flutter

im trying to set default value in the textfield and im not understanting wy this code work

```
final TextEditingController _averageOrderController =
      TextEditingController(text: 37.0.toString());
```

and this code not working

```
double defaultAvgOrder = 37.0;

  final TextEditingController _averageOrderController =
      TextEditingController(text: defaultAvgOrder.toString());
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'code not working'? do you get an error?

Answer (score -1):

You can use TextFormField Widget for initial value.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class TextFormFieldExample extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        String initialValue = "Hello";
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: initialValue,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```